# Transform numbers with exponents to plotmath commands for beautiful legends in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, exp, plotmath

I'm trying to generate a beautiful legend in R plots. I have a `factor=1e-5`, that should appear nicely formatted in the legend. I found a nice function in the package `sfsmisc`, that transforms numbers to expressions. To add this expression to my bquote command, it seems that I need to transform itto a call. unfortunately, there are braces added at the end of the string (`10^-5()`).

Is there a way to avoid the addition of thoses braces? Or is there even an easier way to transform numbers to plotmaths commands for their use in legends? (without doing it manually)

```
factor = 1e-5
alpha = 1:10
omega = alpha^2 * factor

plot (
  alpha
  , omega
  , xlab=bquote(alpha)
  , ylab=bquote(omega)
  , type="b"
  )

text = expression()

# standard version
text[1] = as.expression(bquote(alpha%*%.(factor)))

# beautified version (use pretty10exp from sfsmisc package!?)
library("sfsmisc")
pretty = as.call(pretty10exp(factor, drop.1=T))
text[1] = as.expression(bquote(alpha^2%*%.(pretty)))

# add legend
legend("topleft", legend=text, pch=1, lty=1)
```

[image: screenshot: red arrow points at the braces that should not be there]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do instead with function `parse`:

```
text <- paste("alpha^2%*%",parse(text=pretty10exp(factor,drop.1=T)),sep="")
text
[1] "alpha^2%*%10^-5" # which we then use as the expression in your call to legend
legend("topleft", legend=parse(text=text), pch=1, lty=1)
```

See `?parse` for more explanation on how this work.

Comment: Nice workaround,... I thought there is n easier way. Anyway, first generating the plotmath-command, and then parsing it, is still intuitive,...

Comment: Yes, I tried to find a way to directly concatenate the two expressions (the one with alpha and the pretty10exp output) but couldn't figure it out without building a character string as a prior step like here.