# Include text control characters in plotmath expressions

Tags: r, graphics, plot, expression, plotmath

Is there any way to get control characters for text strings, e.g. `"\n"` for `newline` evaluated inside a plotmath expression, or vice versa. In the following example, I would like to combine:

- some character text
- text control character (newline)
- substitute a variable name
- include a plotmath expression

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15290417/1478381) I can get most of the way there with substitute, but the `newline` character is not evaluated. I am now going round in circles and confusing myself with `plotmath`, `parse`, `bquote` and `substitute`. In the [help page](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) for plotmath it says

> Control characters (e.g. \n) are not interpreted in character strings in plotmath, unlike normal plotting.

Does this mean it really is impossible?

```
lab = "some data"
form = "Exponential"
x = 1:10
y = x^2


plot( x , y , type = "b" )
title( main = substitute( paste( "Plot of " , phi , " of: "  , lab , "\nFunctional form: " , form ) , list(lab = lab , form = form ) ) , adj = 0 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you have figured `plotmath` does not support newlines within, but you can use `mtext` with `bquote`, to write each line.  For example I create a list of lines :

```
Lines <- list(bquote(paste( "Plot of " , phi , " of: "  , .(lab))),
              bquote(paste("Functional form: " , .(form)))

mtext(do.call(expression, Lines),side=3,line=1:0)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works just perfectly! Thank you so much for wading through the quagmire of `bquote` and math/text expressions for me! +1

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here's another solution using unicode and no expressions (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198170/combining-expression-with-n/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192984/displaying-a-greater-than-or-equal-sign/13196615#13196615)):

```
plot(x, y, type="b")
title(main=paste("Plot of \u03A6 of:", lab, "\nFunctional form:", form), adj=0)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks. This is a nice straightforward solution. I didn't even know it was possible to include unicode characters like this. If it were possible to split credit for accepted answers here I would. Thanks!

Comment: As a bit of warning though, some platform/devices don't render all unicode character properly, so it is a good thing that you have agstudy and baptiste solutions as well to fall back on when it happens. See [this blog post](http://bmb-common.blogspot.de/2011/05/unicode-symbols-in-r.html) for some additional tips.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the heads up. You will have probably saved me some additional future headaches when I can't recreate your solution. Thanks again, and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

if you use grid graphics, then the [following grob](https://gist.github.com/baptiste/2732693) can be useful to space the lines according to their height,

```
library(devtools)
source_gist(2732693)
grid.expr(as.expression(Lines))
```

(using agstudy's Lines)