# How do you build R packages with code containing characters supported by R but not by the terminal

Tags: r, terminal

As part of a package I'm creating in R I have a function that calculates a set of values for peptide sequences. The scientific agreement is for these values to be named `yº3`, `bº6`, `xº13`, etc. and so I would like to followed this. In the R GUI (on a Mac at least) `'º'` is an acceptable character, that can be used in character strings etc. meaning that I can successfully create a function outputting a data frame with a column containing the desired names.

The problems come when I try to build the package containing the function. The terminal doesn't understand this character and substitutes it for `\xbc` when running the same function from the build package...

Is there anyway of circumventing this shortcoming of the package builder/terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this solution for a question I asked for a different application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308648/1478381). Unicode is the way to go. As Andrie points out you can use unicode

- [U+00BA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator#) For the masculine ordinal indicator
- [U+00B0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol) For the degree symbol

Include them in the form `\uxxxx` , i.e. small `u` and without the `+`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the solution