# Expression and new line in plot labels

Tags: r, plot, expression, newline

I want to add some subscripts and superscripts to my graph labels. I've try `expression`, but it doesn't work as I wish with new lines (`\n`). I've try to fix it using `paste`, but it doesn't work. Below are some of my tries:

```
par(mfcol=c(1,3))
plot(1,1,main=expression("first line \n second line x"^2))
plot(1,1,main=expression(paste("first line \n second line", "x"^2)))
plot(1,1,main=paste("first line \n second line", expression("x"^2)))
```

It produces:

[image]

In first two pictures the second line is not well centered, in the third one the superscript fails. How to get both centered line and subscripts/superscripts?

Comment: Additionally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297814/include-text-control-characters-in-plotmath-expressions?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198170/combining-expression-with-n on the same subject.

Comment: Upvote: The image immediatly shows you, you've found the right question :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can introduce a line break inside an expression:

```
bquote(atop("first line",
            "second line" ~ x ^ 2))
```

(I’m using `bquote` rather than `expression` here – both work in this case.)

Execute `demo(plotmath)` for more information and look at the documentation for `atop`.

`boxplot` apparently has some trouble interpreting expressions in its title. A simple fix is to plot the title separately:

```
boxplot(data, main = '')
title(bquote(atop("first line", "second line" ~ x ^ 2)))
```

Comment: That's weird: this solution works well with `plot`, but doesn't work with `boxplot`. I've got a message that there was no function called 'atop'.

Comment: @MartaCz-C Curious, you are right. However, the fix is pretty simple – see updated answer.

Answer (score 12):

A fast solution is to add some spaces before the word "first".

Since `plotmath` does not support newlines, you can use `mtext` to create your lines one by one like this:

```
plot(1,1)
exp <- 2
Lines <- list(bquote("first line"),bquote("second line x"^2))
mtext(do.call(expression, Lines),side=3,line=1:0)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I've seen this [somewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300449/1478381) before...! (it is still a great answer)