# Subscript and new Line

Tags: r

I want to make a legend title reading

```
 CO₂-text1
   text2
```

Since `paste()`/`paste0()` doesn't seem to work on expression I also tried using `bquote()` instead, but can't figure a way to add the new line. My most succesfull attempt so far:

```
expression("CO"[2]*"-text1 \n"*" text2")
```

, which results in

```
     -text1
 CO₂         text2
```

Comment: Similar question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549337/expression-and-new-line-in-plot-labels (somehow the solution does not work with my problem, but might be help someone else)

Answer (score 0):

```
expression(atop("CO"[2]~"text1",text2))
```

solved the issue (see question-comments).