# Problem with expression, substitute and eval for a text with 2 lines

Tags: r, plot

I have the next code:

```
area01 <- 122.8
parea01 <- 36.1

text02 <- eval(substitute(expression("L (2510-3410 masl):\n"~a*" "*km^2*"("*s*"%)"),list(a=area01,s=parea01)))
plot(1,1)
title(text02)
```

[image]

I only want that the text does not appear to the right. I want everything in the center. I try too with bquote. It works, but the separation between lines it is too much and I dont want that. I let the solution witn bquote.

```
text02=bquote(bold(atop("L (2510-3410 masl):",.(area01)~km^2~"("~.(parea01)~"%)"),))
```

The problem here is the separation between lines. With expression, works good for me, but I want to ***center it***. Any guess?

Someone help me to resolve my doubt or problem with the code

Comment: I can't reproduce this, because your code doesn't work without the data. `plot(1,1); title( "L (2510-3410 masl):\n122.8 km2(36.1%)")` works fine

Comment: Please either update your example so that it has your data, or include fake sample data

Comment: @Mark which data do you need? if you cant run the code just have `area01 <- 122.8` and `parea01 <- 36.1` then run the code. Also the code you provided above does not produce the desired result ie OP wants to have `km^2` and not `km2`

Comment: thanks @Onyambu. The thing I made was more of an opening gambit

Comment: btw you never replied to me from ages ago, what happened

Comment: @Mark sorry, sometimes I get like 15 inbox messages and I just click on mark all as read without reading any. Could you remind me what that was about?

Comment: @Onyambu it's okay! I understand. I can't find the exact thing rn, but I think you posted a thoughtful comment to me, when I was complaining about how people complain about things no matter what I do. I went to sleep, intending to reply, and the comment was deleted

Comment: I wanted to thank you, but then it was deleted. I tried commenting but you never replied to my questions about it

Comment: Like @Onyambu, it doesnt work your code Mark

Comment: @Felipe my code works, you are just moving the goalposts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another workaround from base R

```
text02 <- sprintf("L (2510-3410 masl):\n %5.1f km²(%4.1f%s)", 
    area01, parea01, "%")
plot(1,1)
title(text02)
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround:

```
pacman::p_load(latex2exp, glue)

plot(1,1)
title(main = TeX(("L (2510-3410 masl):")), line = -1, outer = T)
title(main = TeX(glue("${area01} km^2$ ({parea01}%)")), line = -2, outer = T)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Another workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237295/4145280

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549895/4145280

Comment: btw you don't need to use glue or latex, I just thought it was easier to read

Comment: i dont know if this will work, because i need to replace it en ggplot text lines. I just one text to represent the example. I dont need to do it en "plot". I only need just one script and i need to work in ggplot.

Comment: okay, so you are moving the goalposts

Comment: why don't you create a real example of what you ***actually*** want, and that way I won't answer a dozen questions in between

Comment: Using Tex is the way to go. Great solution btw